# Mouse flickering on certain programs

Tags: hdmi, driver, mouse

I have the raspberry pi 2 with a hdmi - vga monitor running Raspian.

On programs like gimp and things I made in my game, my mouse keeps flickering if I move it across the screen, and if I don't move the mouse the pointer doesn't even show.

Comment: Is it Raspian you are running?

Comment: yes @Bex and with gnome to

Answer (score 1):

```
 Open System Settings > Displays.
```

In the Displays window, you will see an Unknown monitor. Click it and disable it.

Thats a fix I used on Ubuntu when I had a similar issue.

Comment: i am on raspbian with gnome 2